# How to wrapp Reactjs component with CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm pretty new to Reactjs world and I have wrote component that I would love to make beautiful with CSS :)

I have component consisted of few buttons and boxes which would be displayed after button is clicked.

```
class Days extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showComponent: "Box1" };
  }

  toggleDiv = name => {
    if (name === "monday") {
      this.setState({
        showComponent: "Box1"
      });
    } else if (name === "thursday") {
      this.setState({
        showComponent: "Box2"
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.toggleDiv("monday")}>
          <div className="botun">Monday</div>
        </button>
        {this.state.showComponent === "Box1" && <Box1 />}

        <button onClick={() => this.toggleDiv("thursday")}>
          <div className="botun">Thursday</div>
        </button>
        {this.state.showComponent === "Box2" && <Box2 />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Box1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <h1>BOx1</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Box2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <h1>Box2</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

After button1 is clicked belonging boxes will be shown under.

So my question is how to put all buttons and boxes into one container and style it like in screenshot?

If I include it in my landingpage.js like this

```
<div className="container">
 <div className="row">
  <Days />
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I still make my buttons be in one line?

I am not sure how to approach this with CSS.

What is the best practice when using CSS and CSS frameworks with ReactJS?

I am using global style.css and Boostrap.

Comment: *I am not sure how to approach this with CSS, for example how to put this buttons to be in one line and also boxes in line under it?* - likely the same way as with plain HTML and CSS. But they already look this way on the screenshot, don't they?

Comment: Have edited my question a bit, please take a look. @estus

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap all your buttons inside a single div, give the container a single class, give it's children a modifier class when they are active and if you want to animate the display of the boxes then you shouldn't unmount them when another button is active opting for making them invisible or something like that because otherwise it's kinda difficult to not have React just pop them into existence.

Comment: I have edited my question a bit for better understanding, I do understand that I need to wrap it in singe div and then in div container. You can see my edit. But also not quite sure if my approach above is right. Functionality is working just the way I want it is's just CSS :O

Answer (score 0):

I use inline style tags. It's really a personal preference situation. As you try new things you'll discover the practice that's best for you and for individual projects.     An inline style tag looks like this.`<div style={{ display: 'flex', width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'red' }}></div>` the benefit to this is you can keep styles defined in the component.